C# Application + Certum Code signing, Microsoft Defender SmartScreen still reacts?
I'm new to code signing so maybe my error is just an obvious user error.
I bought the Open Source Code Signing - set from Certum.
Open Source Code Signing - set
I created a very simple C# WinForms App
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MessageBox.Show("Text in the Textbox will be saved in File.txt");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "File.txt"), textBox1.Text);
}

I signed the .exe file using the signtool with this command:
signtool.exe sign /n "My Name Here" /t http://time.certum.pl /fd sha256 /v "PathToMySimpleExeFile" <- I got this command from the Certum documentation!
I confirmed that the .exe file got the certification applied by using the context menu -> Properties -> Digital Signatures
Sofar, so good!
I zipped the File and sended it via Discord to a friend. But unfortunally, he still gets the Microsoft Defender SmartScreen
SmartScreen Image
I removed my Name because of personal reasons
What am I missing? :0
Do I need to wait a few days?
I'm just so confused!

Signing is one thing but beyond that  your app needs a certain reputation/trust (read a number of installations) before beeing considerd safe by SmartScreen so it no longer warns about that app.

Another option is to get an EV code-signing certificate.  They are more expensive and harder to get but once you get them, the Smart Screen problem disappears right away.  You don't have to wait for all those installs.

Thankyou Ralf and Joe. This helped me a TON!
Guess my users will have to get used to the SmartScreen :D
